# Only one field left in the table - while solving localization

Tags: mysql, database-design, internationalization

While trying to move table fields that are to be translated into several languages into *_i18n tables I came to situation when my tables(author, abstract_book, publisher) were left with only 1 field. My teacher says that it is a bad practice to have tables that do not have any fields but id. Is there any better way to do this?
[image: database model]

Comment: every 1:n or n:m relationship needs a bridge table

Comment: @nbk - False.  n:m needs a bridge table; 1:n does not.

Comment: I see no need for those three 1-column tables.  I question the need for `language`.  Seems like there are standard, not-to-long, strings that could be used for "language".  What comes to mind is en_US, en_GB, pt_PT, pt_BR, etc. (http://quivi.sourceforge.net/languagecodes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to say an author's name (or a person's name at that) is always the same, but then I remembered that Jules Verne is really called Julio Verne in some Spanish speaking countries and we call Mr. Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский Dostojewski in German and Dostoevsky in English.

While ID-only tables look a bit strange, they can still serve for referential integrity. You cannot have a book with an author ID that doesn't exist for instance. But you could still have instances without any language entry. E.g. Book 1 was written by authors 2 and 3, but we don't know the book's title or the authors' names. That's the big drawback of this design.

For this reason I'd add columns to the tables for identification. There are three approaches to this:

- Add the real name (author's name, book's title, publisher's name) to the table. That would be the author 'Достоевский' for instance.
- Add the name in a default language (e.g. English) to the table. That would be the author 'Dostoevsky' for instance. With this approach you would ensure that data for the default language would be complete. (While data in other languages may have gaps.)
- Add a reference to the i18n table's row (again original language or default language) to the table. This, however, has the problem that you want to have the reference not nullable, so the tables would be cross referenced. This calls for deferrable constraints and these are not available in MySQL.

Whichever of these three approaches you prefer, they all do the same: The table has an ID and a name/title. Thus you have a default, when an I18N entry is missing. And you can detect errors. If author 1 is called 'Jules Verne' in the author table and his French name is 'Jules Verne' and his English name is 'Mary Shelley', then you know which entry is incorrect :-)